# how to call focusout event on UIdatePicker in Ipad

Tags: ipad, jquery-ui

In my project,jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js is used to create UIdatePicker. In HTML page , UIDatePicker is defined as below :

```
<input id='input_birthdate' class='inputText input big,ui-datepicker-title-custom' type="text" maxlength="64" tabindex="7" style ="position: relative; z-index: 1000;" />

If I inspect this particuler field in HTML page in Firefox browser , I can see the IDs and Classes declared in jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js are being used.(I don't know how jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js is used on input_birthdate).

If I am declaring as below in some JavaScript page , it works both in laptop browser and ipad but Its not allowing to select any year or month as div is getting closed.

$("#input_birthdate").focusout(function() {
   $("#input_birthdate").datepicker("hide");
});

I noticed that datepicker is made of several components,so I thought of applying focusout on parent div as below:

$('#ui-datepicker-div').focusout(function(){
     $('#ui-datepicker-div').datepicker("hide");
});

But now its not working on IPAD.

Kindly suggest where I am going wrong or any other alternative to fix this.
```

Comment: After lot of google search , I got to know that focusout doesn't work in IPAD but If it is not working then how come this code worked in Ipad :                            $("#input_birthdate").focusout(function() {
   $("#input_birthdate").datepicker("hide");
});                                                                  My concern is why above code worked and why not below code is working :                                                      $('#ui-datepicker-div').focusout(function(){
     $('#ui-datepicker-div').datepicker("hide");
});

Comment: @Dnister Lark You have faced similar issue as per your [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339012/catch-next-and-prev-buttons-on-ipadipod-devices-via-javascripjquery).I am also facing that issue.Can you please help me out with the approach you followed for resolving that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following function should work on iPad

$("#input_birthdate").blur(function() 
{
  $("#input_birthdate").datepicker("hide");
});

Comment: This option is also not allowing me to select any year or month as its getting hidden on click of year range and month range component.